# Optimizing Apache Spark on Kubernetes using custom plugins and the scheduling framework

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, plugins, scheduler

My goal is to optimally run Spark applications alongside the stateless workload in my cluster to make the best use of my cluster resources.

Since Spark applications can suffer from partial scheduling (drivers blocking the executors as the driver pods are started first which then request for the executor pods), a simple strategy to prevent this would be to implement the much talked about gang/co-scheduling to make sure that we only start the driver pod if we can guarantee that all the executors can be started in the future by implementing some kind of a reservations design such that the driver can reserve resources for the executors that will be started in the future.

Also, this reservation definition/implementation must be visible to all the other non-spark pods as well since they would also have to log their resource requests like the Spark pods so we have a clear picture of the cluster resource utilization.

The current implementations include running a new custom scheduler or implementing a scheduler extender to do so but I was wondering if we can achieve this by writing custom scheduler plugins. Additionally, what extension points in the scheduling framework would the plugins have to take advantage of to optimize the scheduling of Spark jobs in a multi-tenant environment (with different kinds of workload) so that my default profile can continue to schedule the stateless workload while the custom profile that uses these plugins can schedule Spark applications?

Finally, would this be the best way to optimize scheduling Spark and Stateless workload in a multi-tenant environment? What would the drawbacks of this approach (using custom plugins) be since we only have a single queue that all the profiles must share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you would like to have is [Gang Scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_scheduling) . If you'd like to have that capability, I suggest you use [Volcano](https://github.com/volcano-sh/volcano) to schedule/run  your jobs in Kubernetes with [Gang Scheduling](https://volcano.sh/docs/scheduler-reclaim/#gang-1).

Another approach is to create your own scheduler using the [scheduler extender](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/scheduling/scheduler_extender.md) as described [here](https://medium.com/palantir/spark-scheduling-in-kubernetes-4976333235f3) or use the [Palantir gang scheduler extender](https://github.com/palantir/k8s-spark-scheduler).

✌️

Comment: Thanks for your response, Rico!

Won't these implementations have to run alongside the default scheduler? We might be facing issues like cache synchronization, resource conflicts, race conditions when both the default-scheduler and Volcano Scheduler pick the same node with resources available for only one scheduler's pods.

In the case Palantir's scheduler extender, the resource reservations made for Spark pods will not be visible by the pods scheduled by the default scheduler. Technically, I would want  the non-spark pods to also create reservations to have a knowledge of the cluster?

Comment: Yes, but you could limit the where your pods are run using other tools like PodAffinity, nodeaffinity and also specify the scheduler that you want to use in your pod definition: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/#specify-schedulers-for-pods

Comment: Yes, I agree. But would I be achieving maximum utilization of my cluster resources in case I use nodeaffinity/anti-affinity to limit/control where my pods are run? Since my goal is to run both stateless workload and Spark workload (with gang-scheduling) on all my nodes in a single cluster while trying to utilize the available cluster resources to maximum capacity.

Comment: That's where our jobs come into play  You need to balance scheduler, cpu, memory, etc. Kubernetes and its tools help but K8s is not a silver bullet when it comes to achieving maximum resource utilization.

Comment: Hmm, I see...thanks, Rico! Could you please elaborate on how we can automate this balancing and what the preferred methods are to achieve the same?